# Razor C# output of non-english characters

Tags: c#, database, loops, razor, encoding

Razor C# newbe here,

I have the following code:

```
@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
{                           
@: ["@row.Table1", "@row.Table2", "@row.Table3", "@row.Table4", "@row.Table5", "@row.Table6", "@row.Table7",],                                                   
}
```

That loops out content from my database. However since I'm from Sweden I need to use the non-english characters "å, ä, ö" and these do not show correctly.

Looking at what's rendered, here for example `"k&#246;p"` the letter `"ö"` is replaced by `"&#246;"` instead. What i would want is to have the correct letter replacing this, or to know if there is some method I can use to solve this problem.

Using UTF-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is HTML Encoding. Try one of these solutions

```
@Html.Raw("k&#246;p")
@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("k&#246;p")
@(new HtmlString("k&#246;p"))
@MvcHtmlString.Create("k&#246;p")
```

Comment: Thank you! Though I've just started playing around with Razor C# (learning by doing) so to be honest I don't really know how to implement this. Are you able to give me a hint?

Comment: Yes, sure. I think you should write something like this:

@foreach(var row in db.Query(selectQueryString))
{
    @Html.Raw(raw.SomeColumnName)
}

Comment: If you use WebMatrix, here is some example [Microsoft WebMatrix Tutorial Series](http://evonet.com.au/webmatrix-retrieving-content-from-a-database/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Server.HtmlEncode("Your Unicode Text").

Comment: Seems like that won't solve the problem unfortunately, still getting the same result.